# What is the difference between motivation and intuition of a theorem/result?

Tags: soft-question, intuition, education, learning, motivation

What is the difference between motivation and intuition of a theorem/result? Are they same or different in some way?

**Edit 1**

To me intuition appears as the set of ideas (which may or may not contain part of the formal proof?) which validates our result (partially or fully?) and motivation as the set of ideas that induces/inspires the birth of a different result.

So, suppose we didn't knew about Fermat's Little Theorem, and then we see the pattern- $2|(a^2-a)$, $3|(a^3-a)$, $5|(a^5-a)$- each one of which having it's own separate proof established through algebra, so does this(& similarly other ones which are mathematically similar to these and whose divisor is a prime) set of results act as a motivation(induces/inspires) or intuition(partially validates/verifies on a case by basis) for Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: I would think 'motivation' is why we should go that direction in the first place, while 'intuition' is simple informal arguments why it should be true at all.  So, motivation leads to the statement of a result, intuition is the informal 'proof'.

Comment: I usually think of motivation of a theorem as it being inspired by some idea, and the intuition behind a theorem is a rough idea for why you should believe it to be true.

Comment: IMO they are different in many ways. Intuition can build motivation often times, less so the other way around. There was massive motivation to prove FLT for hundreds of years, but little intuition to support it.

Comment: My view on this is, roughly, that motivation is something that explains or suggests _that_ something might be true. Intuition, however, suggests _why_ something is true. Hence partial results, like special cases of Fermat's little theorem as you mention, are a motivation, because they suggests that something more is going on out there, in your case - we have the general Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Motivation can also refer to why a theorem is useful, as in the motivation behind integral calculus is calculate the area of non-trivial shapes.